# How to estimate parameters of an Extended Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter, state-space-models

I am slightly familiar with how to estimate the parameters in a linear Kalman Filter, by using maximum likelihood. Do we do the same for the extended Kalman Filter? In particular, I am confused as to how to set up the log likelihood equation. the general expression that I have seen so far involves some integrals, and it is not clear to me exactly whether it is just the product of normal distribution or not

Comment: did you check the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter#Discrete-time_predict_and_update_equations)? it has the update and predict equations there

Comment: @bdeonovic  Thanks! Yeah, but I want to estimate the parameters, I assume that I can do it with maximum likelihood assuming that the errors are jointly normal but I'm not 100% sure. I couldn't find anything explicit online –

Comment: With Markov Chain Monte Carlo method, you can get the estimator of parameters. But I never tried EKF before as in the case for non linear transition and observation equation, I will use particle marginal metropolis hastings algorithm to do that.

Comment: @Fly_back do you know where I can find some resources to apply a MCMC? I have not used it before, and my experience so far is with kaman filters. Also, I think i figured out how to do the ML on the extended. It's essentially the same normal function as in the linear case.

Comment: @dleal please read this paper http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/andrieu_doucet_holenstein_PMCMC.pdf for more details.